# IE v9 and below not switching thumbnail images with large image

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Clicking each thumbnail on the side of the product page will switch the big_image to show that image as normal. Works fine on anything other than Internet Explorer 9 or lower. I therefore added a little jQuery a moment ago but still not working on any of those versions. Any ideas?

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1bEfjYf

```
<?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="image-additional">
        <a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img class="side_thumb" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a>

        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img class="side_thumb"  src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big_image">
        <img width="320" height="320" name="main" src="<?php echo $popup; ?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.image-additional img').click(function() {
                var img = $(this).attr('src');
                $('#big_image img').attr('src', img);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery 2.0 dropped support for some older browsers, so if that's the case you may be able to fix this by switching to jQuery 1.11.0

Comment: @MatthewDaly on live site, OP is using `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`. BTW, his site is working fine for me under IE9-. Indeed, i'm unable to reproduce issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Cheers, missed the link. Probably worth upgrading to 1.11.0 if possible anyway as 1.7 is pretty old